# building form in drupal 7 - checkbox value insert into database

Tags: forms, checkbox, drupal-7

Im trying to get checkbox values into SQL database but get this ERROR MESSAGE:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1: INSERT INTO {1test} (personnummer, arende, kampanj) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2_ett, :db_insert_placeholder_2_tva, :db_insert_placeholder_2_tre); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 8007289690 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => saldo [:db_insert_placeholder_2_ett] => ett [:db_insert_placeholder_2_tva] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_2_tre] => 0 ) in my_module_my_form_submit() (line 118 of C:\acquia-drupal-sites\sql\sites\all\modules\1-custom\my_module\my_module.module).

My Form_Module:

```
$form['kampanj'] = array(
 '#default_value' => array(
  ),
 '#required' => '0',
 '#key_type_toggled' => '0',
 '#weight' => '2',
   '#type' => 'checkboxes',
'#options' => array(
'ett' => t('ett'),
'tva' => t('två'),
'tre' => t('tre'),
 ),
 '#title' => t('Kampanj'),
 );

function my_module_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$personnummer = db_insert('1test')
->fields(array(

'kampanj' => $form_state['values']['kampanj']


))
->execute();
drupal_set_message(t('Registrerat.'));
```

}

Comment: first off, your form is not set to required, so it may be submitted without a value, this should be checked in the submit handler. How many columns are in your '1test' table and what data type are they?

Comment: Yes the form is not set to required since I am still testing the form.
1test table has 4 columns: id(bigint), id-number(longtext), items(text), kampanj(text)

Answer (score 0):

If your table has 4 columns, then you need to send it 4 values in the fields function array. You are only sending it 1. Hence the error:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I think in the array you send to the fields function you need to have 4 values with the array key corresponding to the table column. send Null for the id

eg.

```
->fields(array(
'id' => null,
'id-number' => 'something',
'items' => 'something,
'kampanj' => $form_state['values']['kampanj'],
))
```

Also, is the value of 'kampanj' actually text as the database is expecting?

Comment: first column in table is primary key which is auto-genereated and i t works well(4 coluemns in table and it gets only two values from the form) until I add the checkbox to form. This checkbox seems to try to send all three values from the checkbox to three columns. All I want is that all values go to one column.

Comment: The value of "kampanj" is text. The error message is suggesting that 3 values? are being sent to column "kampanj" when I only need one value.


db_insert_placeholder_4_ett, :db_insert_placeholder_4_tva, :db_insert_placeholder_4_tre

Comment: check the value of $form_state['values']['kampanj']. Is it what you are expecting?

Comment: I am expecting only one value(one checkbox selected>ett) but to me it looks like all three(ett, tva, tre) values are being sent to database.
Everything else(select lists and radio buttons) in the form functions correct.

Comment: install the devel module and print out the contents of $form_state['values']['kampanj'] with the dpm function to be sure.

Comment: I installed the devel module however it doesn't print what I want. This is the code I added:

`dpm($form_state['values']['kampanj']);`


... (Array, 9 elements)
 8: my_module3_my_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 7: call_user_func_array() (Array, 1 element)
 6: drupal_retrieve_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 5: drupal_build_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 4: drupal_get_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 3: my_module3_form() (Array, 2 elements) Get path
 2: call_user_func_array() (Array, 1 element)
 1: menu_execute_active_handler() (Array, 2 elements)
 0: main() (Array, 2 elements)

Comment: `... (Array, 9 elements)
 8: my_module3_my_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 7: call_user_func_array() (Array, 1 element)
 6: drupal_retrieve_form() (Array, 2 elements) Get path
 5: drupal_build_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 4: drupal_get_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 3: my_module3_form() (Array, 2 elements)
 2: call_user_func_array() (Array, 1 element)
 1: menu_execute_active_handler() (Array, 2 elements)
 0: main() (Array, 2 elements)
Krumo version 0.2.1a | http://krumo.sourceforge.net Click to expand.  `

Comment: let's try this way, below is the text with php code that I use in my module:

[link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32248859/my_module.txt

Comment: devel message and errors
[link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32248859/devel.txt